# SqlDependency not working mvc app. Hits once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

I am following the blog http://www.venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ to get a signalR push message out to connected clients. 
My debugger never hits the onchange event.

my Global.asax.cs:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

protected void Application_Start()
{
     // basic stuff
     SqlDependency.Start(connString);
     var repo = new Repositories.MarkerRepository();
     repo.GetAllMarkers(); // to register the dependency
}
```

My MarkerRepository.cs:

```
    readonly string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    private MarkersHub _mh = new MarkersHub(); // my signalr hub class

    public IEnumerable<House> GetAllMarkers()
    {
        var markers = new List<House>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo].Houses", connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    markers.Add(item: new House {
                        ID        = (int)reader["ID"],
                        Name      = (string)reader["Name"],
                        Code      = reader["Code"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["Code"] : "",
                        Latitude  = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Latitude"]),
                        Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Longitude"])
                    });
                }
            }

        }
        return markers;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            _mh.SendMarkers();
        }
    }
```

I have had a hit once but it was no change, only a notification for subscribe. I have read a lot about resubscribe, but when it hit this event the sql:

```
select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions
```

still returns no rows. Not on my db or master. So **I think that there is an error in the blog post with the re-subscribe to the on change event**? This sample https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(VS.80).aspx does unregister in the onchange event and calls the method which registers a new event. Can someone verify my assumption?

Comment: Not sure but in this line  `var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo].Houses", connection)` are you supposed to put the `@` there? Because you are just querying data not Creating, updating or deleting. This is probably unrelated to your issue so I'm sorry I can't be of more help. Your dependency_onchange method looks correct to me, it's almost exactly how I've done it in my project.

Comment: @Dennis1679 it is no multiline string, so the @ is not needed. But The thing is that when the `dependency_OnChange` is fired. The `SqlNotificationEventArgs.Type` is of type `SqlNotificationType.Subscribe` which is an error according to the msdn docs. I will have to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were the values for the `SqlNotificationEventArgs e` in my event and told me that my query to depend on, was invalid.

`SqlNotificationEventArgs.Type` --> `SqlNotificationType.Subscribe`

`SqlNotificationEventArgs.Info` --> `SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid`

`SqlNotificationEventArgs.Source` --> `SqlNotificationSource.Statement`

> The statement may not use the asterisk (*) or table_name.* syntax to specify columns.

source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx